# Is it possible to enter bios using an external monitor on a Vaio VGN-FE21S?

Tags: bios, external-display, sony-vaio

The manual says Fn+F7 should switch to the external display but this isn't working for me at power on. The internal LCD is dead so I was hoping to be able to enter BIOS using the external monitor.

Anyone have a workaround for this? In case it is relevant, the LCD and housing are completely removed from the laptop and I'm using a USB keyboard.

If I let the computer boot completely, the external monitor does work so it doesn't seem to be a graphics chip failure.